# How to add On-screen button to PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferences

I' m using AndroidX Preference library version 1.1.1. It provides components like `SwitchPreferenceCompat` and `MultiSelectListPreference`.

And in [Android Settings Design Guidelines](https://source.android.google.cn/devices/tech/settings/settings-guidelines#on-screen_button), there are samples of `On-screen button` component, when the Preference API does not provide any sub components of button. [image: On-screen button in Settings Page Design Guidelines]

I know there are more than 10 questions about **how to** add button here in stackoverflow, but I just don' t understand **why** we have to add custom layout by ourselves. Isn' t it(I mean, buttons in Setting Screen) an officially recommended standard practice? **LOGOUT** or **CLEAR DATA** buttons are common at the end of app' s setting page. I am confused.

Comment: Great question... They also talk about adding [notes](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/settings/settings-guidelines) on the settings pages but I have yet to find a simple way to do that. Unfortunately you'll probably end up having to make your own `ButtonPreference` or something...

Comment: @Tyler V I have my custom TimePickerPreference, which makes my code a lot more. If a simple button had to do the same, it is really disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I know why now...

The number, arrangement, and style of buttons at footer are depend on the needs, so a custom preference is necessary. In fact, we have to do the same when we want to change the layout or style of a given standard preference.

In androidX Preference instead of old Preference, it is easier than before:

```
class FooterPreference(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): Preference(context, attrs) {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PreferenceViewHolder?) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder)
        holder?.itemView?.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn)?.setOnClickListener {

        }
    }
}
```